# How to update a file in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I know that HDFS is write once and read many times.
Suppose if i want to update a file in HDFS is there any way to do it ?

Thankyou in advance !

Answer (score 24):

**Option1:**

If you just want to append to an existing file

1. `echo "<Text to append>" | hdfs dfs -appendToFile - /user/hduser/myfile.txt` OR
2. `hdfs dfs -appendToFile - /user/hduser/myfile.txt` and then type the text on the terminal. Once you are done typing then hit 'Ctrl+D'

**Option2:**

Get the original file from HDFS to the local filesystem, modify it and then put it back on HDFS.

1. `hdfs dfs -get /user/hduser/myfile.txt`
2. `vi myfile.txt` #or use any other tool and modify it
3. `hdfs dfs -put -f myfile.txt /user/hduser/myfile.txt`

Comment: I'm aware this is almost a year old, but for anyone that may be looking for the answer - In option 2, putting a file that already exists will cause an error. You'll need to move/rename/remove the file from HDFS first. you can rename it with `hdfs dfs -mv /home/hduser/myfile.txt /home/hduser/old_myfile.txt`

Comment: Or you can simply add `-f` flag for `put` command. Updated answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add lines, you must put another file and concatenate files:

```
hdfs dfs -appendToFile localfile /user/hadoop/hadoopfile
```

To modify any portion of a file that is already written you have three options:

1. Get file from hdfs and modify their content in local

   `hdfs dfs -copyToLocal /hdfs/source/path /localfs/destination/path`

   or

   `hdfs dfs -cat /hdfs/source/path | modify...`
2. Use a processing technology to update as [Map Reduce](http://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2016/02/09/python-tutorial.html) or  [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/examples.html), the result will appear as a directory of files and you will remove old files. It should be the best way.
3. Install NFS or Fuse, both supports append operations.

   [NFS Gateway](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html)

   [Hadoop Fuse](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/MountableHDFS) : mountableHDFS, helps allowing HDFS to be mounted (on most flavors of Unix) as a standard file system using the mount command. Once mounted, the user can operate on an instance of hdfs using standard Unix utilities such as ‘ls’, ‘cd’, ‘cp’, ‘mkdir’, ‘find’, ‘grep’