# HDFS: Errno 22 on attempt to edit an existing file in mounted NFS volume

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, nfs, jupyter-lab

**Summary**: I mounted HDFS nfs volume in OSX and it will not let me edit existing files. I can append and create files with content but not "open them with `write` flag".

Originally, I asked about a particular problem with JupyterLab failing to save notebooks into nfs mounted volumes but while trying to dig down to the roots, I realized (hopefully right) that it's about editing existing files.

I mounted HDFS nfs on OSX and I can access the files, read and write and whatnot. JupyterLab though can do pretty much everything but can't really save notebooks.

I was able to identify the pattern for what's really happening and the problem boils down to this: you can't open *existing* files in nfs volume for write:

This will work with a **new** file:

```
with open("rand.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write("random text")
```

But if you try to run it again (the file has been created now and the content is there), you'll get the following Exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-94a46812fad4> in <module>()
----> 1 with open("rand.txt", 'w') as f:
      2     f.write("random text")

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'rand.txt'
```

I am pretty sure the permissions and all are ok:

```
with open("seven.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write("random text")
    f.writelines(["one","two","three"])

r = open("seven.txt", 'r')
print(r.read())
```

> random textonetwothree

I can also append to files no problem:

```
aleksandrs-mbp:direct sasha$ echo "Another line of text" >> seven.txt && cat seven.txt 
random textonetwothreeAnother line of text
```

I mount it with the following options:

> aleksandrs-mbp:hadoop sasha$ mount -t nfs -o
> vers=3,proto=tcp,nolock,noacl,sync localhost:/
> /srv/ti/jupyter-samples/~Hadoop

Apache documentation suggests that NFS gateway does not support random writes. I tried looking at `mount` documentation but could not find anything specific that points to enforcing sequential writing. I tried playing with different options but it doesn't seem to help much.

This is the exception I get from JupyterLab when it's trying to save the notebook:

```
[I 03:03:33.969 LabApp] Saving file at /~Hadoop/direct/One.ipynb
[E 03:03:33.980 LabApp] Error while saving file: ~Hadoop/direct/One.ipynb [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/srv/ti/jupyter-samples/~Hadoop/direct/.~One.ipynb'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/filemanager.py", line 471, in save
        self._save_notebook(os_path, nb)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/fileio.py", line 293, in _save_notebook
        with self.atomic_writing(os_path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 82, in __enter__
        return next(self.gen)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/fileio.py", line 213, in atomic_writing
        with atomic_writing(os_path, *args, log=self.log, **kwargs) as f:
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 82, in __enter__
        return next(self.gen)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/fileio.py", line 103, in atomic_writing
        copy2_safe(path, tmp_path, log=log)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/contents/fileio.py", line 51, in copy2_safe
        shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 115, in copyfile
        with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
    OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/srv/ti/jupyter-samples/~Hadoop/direct/.~One.ipynb'
[W 03:03:33.981 LabApp] 500 PUT /api/contents/~Hadoop/direct/One.ipynb?1534835013966 (::1): Unexpected error while saving file: ~Hadoop/direct/One.ipynb [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/srv/ti/jupyter-samples/~Hadoop/direct/.~One.ipynb'
[W 03:03:33.981 LabApp] Unexpected error while saving file: ~Hadoop/direct/One.ipynb [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/srv/ti/jupyter-samples/~Hadoop/direct/.~One.ipynb'
```

This is what I see in the NFS logs at the same time:

```
2018-08-21 03:05:34,006 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.nfs.nfs3.RpcProgramNfs3: Setting file size is not supported when setattr, fileId: 16417
2018-08-21 03:05:34,006 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.nfs.nfs3.RpcProgramNfs3: Setting file size is not supported when setattr, fileId: 16417
```

Not exactly sure what this means but if I understand [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1813), it should be part of implementation:

> Servers must support extending the file size via SETATTR.

I understand the complexity behind mounting hdfs and letting clients write all they want while keeping these files distributed and maintain integrity. Is there though a compromise that would enable writes via nfs?

Comment: This question already has an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39130092/how-to-update-a-file-in-hdfs

Comment: @John Considering that doesn't mention how to use NFS gateway, I'd say it's not an answer that's looked for

Comment: In any case, I'd recommend you install Pyspark (or setup Apache Toree for Jupyter), as Spark will be far more more useful than raw Python scripts reading/writing plain text from HDFS because that's a suboptimal format for HDFS and HDFS hates lots of tiny files, so you're Python code would typically be buffering rather large files (several GB) in a production environment, therefore not a good idea to use what you have

Comment: HDFS is WORM. This means that you cannot modify the existing contents of a file. You can create a new file, append to an existing file, but you cannot modify the existing contents. Yes, the link I provided states this. NFS makes no different to HDFS.