# Using mssql-tools bcp from HDFS NFS mount

Tags: hdfs, bcp

Trying to run `bcp` from the `mssql-tools` package (using centos7) to export tsv file data from **an HDFS location mounted to local FS via [NFS Gateway](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/data-storage/content/using_the_nfs_gateway_for_accessing_hdfs.html)**, but running into errors like...

> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>
> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP error-file

or

> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
>
> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file

The bcp command being run looks like...

```sh
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp "$TABLE" in \
        "$filename" \
        $TO_SERVER_ODBCDSN \
        -U $USER -P $PASSWORD \
        -d $DB \
        $RECOMMEDED_IMPORT_MODE \
        -t "\t" \
        -e ${filename}.bcperror.log

# with the actual commmand w/ variables resolved looks like...
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp "ACCOUNT" in \
    "/HDFS_NFS/path/to/tsv/1_0_0.tsv" \
    -D -S MyMSSQLServer \
    -U myuser -P mypassword \
    -d SOME_MSSQL_DB \
    -c \
    -t \t \
    -e /HDFS_NFS/path/to/store/errlogs/1_0_0.tsv.bcperror.log
```

all of this seems fine to me, yet also *sometimes* getting errors like...

> /opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp:  unknown option
>
> usage: /opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile ...

so not sure what that's about either. My `/etc/odbc.ini` file looks like...

```sh
[MyMSSQLServer]
Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Description=My MS SQL Server
Trace=No
Server=<the server's IP>
```

Anyone know any further debugging tips or fixes for this?

Comment: how are you executing the bcp command? by hand in cmd window? via xp_cmdshell, via SSIS package? also can you paste in your bcp command being executed?

Comment: @jamie Executing via a bash script. Was hoping to avoid pasting the full code (as I realize there may be many things affecting it) as it's a bit involved. Will try to pare it down to essentials and update.

Comment: no need to paste the full code, just paste in the command that your script is building. skip all the variables and declarations, just capture what you have built for the actual bcp command and paste here. When building a command dynamically and getting errors on execution, i think it usually comes down to the command not being what we think it should be.

Comment: this sounds like a permission issue, but can also be that any files referenced int eh command are not there or are locked. The error is accurate (as I have encountered it in my time). BCP either cannot open or cannot find the files mentioned. BTW the "error file" (using the -e option) is only going to show data errors, not errors with regard to connectivity or other such errors... just data errors.

Comment: @jamie Posted bcp command. Though, from your comments, thinking this more likely is an issue with the HDFS NFS Gateway. Continuing to debug...

Comment: some other troubleshooting I would do in a case like this: 1 can you run the command by hand? take what is built of the bcp command and execute it at a command line? 2 what account is executing the bash script? That is the account you should log in as and try to execute the command by hand. 3 using the account that actually executes the bash script, try to simply access the file from where the script is executed. Confirm the paths exist. Maybe eliminate the -e option for now from your testing/manual execution. It's not needed for testing and if it is the issue, you'll see then.

Comment: Im not familiar with the -D (capital D) option. I dont see that as an option in MS SQL Server documentation or Sybase. You would be getting a different error if that were a problem, so not sure about that. Do you know what the -D is used for?

Comment: @jamie "`-D` option: Causes the value passed to the bcp `-S` option to be interpreted as a data source name (DSN)." I use this for using a `/etc/odbc.ini` file rather than a IP string literal. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/connecting-with-bcp?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: And yes, this very likely is not a BCP question. This looks more like a permissions issue. Probably network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the error logging file specified by the `-e` option was **already existing** in the location specified and that **HDFS (mounted via NFS or not) did not like** the bcp command trying to overwrite it. You would normally do something like

```sh
hadoop fs -put -f /some/local/file /hdfs/location/for/file
```

and I assume that bcp was attempting something else via the NFS gateway that was not this. I suppose there also could have been latency problems with bcp accessing the HDFS NFS location. Running the bcp command without the `-e` option worked in the example originally posted.

** As a workaround, based on another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39136947/8236733), I bring the files down (`hadoop fs -get ...`) to a local temp dir `/home/user/tmp/<some uuid>/` and do what needs to be done there, then `hadoop fs -put ...`.